# Playing alert sounds from terminal

Tags: terminal, audio, bash

Is there a way to play OSX alert sounds from terminal? The alert sounds that are listed in System Preferences > Sound > Sound Effect Tab

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you have "audible bell" enabled in your Terminal Settings under Advanced, BEL control characters will sound the default alert sound.

To try this, issue the `echo` command followed by <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.  If you type it right, it will look like this:

```
$ echo ^G
```

and when you press <kbd>return</kbd>, the alert will sound.

(<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> is a shell escape for the immediately-following control character.)

The `afplay` command can also be used to play a specific sound file:

```
$ afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Funk.aiff
```

Comment: I use this for playing sounds in MAMP PRO: <? passthru('/usr/bin/afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Sosumi.aiff'); ?>

Answer (score 11):

I like zigg's solution. In order to keep it short I did this:

In `/Users/{username}/.bash_profile` add a line

```
alias taskready='afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Hero.aiff'
```

Quit the terminal and open the terminal. Now you can use the shorthand command `taskready`.

You can choose from:

```
Basso.aiff  Frog.aiff   Hero.aiff   Pop.aiff    Submarine.aiff
Blow.aiff   Funk.aiff   Morse.aiff  Purr.aiff   Tink.aiff
Bottle.aiff Glass.aiff  Ping.aiff   Sosumi.aiff
```

Comment: `done` is used in bash to close for/while loops, maybe a different name might be better

Comment: @nohillside it luckily didn't cause any problems so far... thanks! Do you have a short keyword suggestion?

Comment: See `man bash` for all keywords to avoid :-)

Answer (score 10):

Another option, with less modifier keys, is to use the command `tput bel`.

Comment: I liked this answer because I disabled the "audible bell" in my terminal settings, but `tput bel` calls the "visual bell" so I still get the alert that I want without the noisy one

Comment: Today, [the accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/96371/194611) (`echo` ctrl+v ctrl+g) also shows the visible bell when my Mac is muted. Glad they fixed this since 2016

Answer (score 7):

Not exactly what OP wants but may still prove useful to people.

`say beep`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to beep is `echo -e '\a'`